# Check if timedelta is greater than value (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a panda dataframe with multiple transactions and want to check if the gap between each transaction is greater than 10 minutes. If so I want to create a new Panda Dataframe with each transaction that went over 10 minutes.

```
4/29/20 5:53 AM
4/29/20 6:08 AM
4/29/20 6:09 AM
4/29/20 6:12 AM
4/29/20 6:18 AM
4/29/20 6:53 AM
4/29/20 7:31 AM
4/29/20 7:58 AM
4/29/20 8:28 AM
4/29/20 8:28 AM
4/29/20 9:06 AM
4/29/20 9:38 AM
4/29/20 9:47 AM
4/29/20 10:13 AM
4/29/20 11:04 AM
4/29/20 12:52 PM
```

Comment: it would be easier for anyone to help if you can have a dataframe rather than an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, sort your dataset by time. if the time column is not in datetime format convert it to datetime using this code:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

then create a column for time differences (in minutes) for two consecutive rows:

```
df['time_diff_min'] = (df['time'].shift(-1) - df['time']).dt.total_seconds() / 60
```

Now you only need to filter the new column:

```
df[df['time_diff_min'] > 10]
```

let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a normal comparison with string:

```
# convert to datetime type
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

# time difference greater than 10 minutes
df['Time'].diff().gt('10Min')
```

Output:

```
0     False
1      True
2     False
3     False
4     False
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9     False
10     True
11     True
12    False
13     True
14     True
15     True
Name: Time, dtype: bool
```